# I want read "PUB" string and if found then read next 50 character and append in excel file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to code where i have date in t1.txt like below:

```
table             column size time
PUB.emp            20    1k   00.4
PUB.dept           10    3k   003
PUB.tst            34    1K   034
```

I am want out like

```
PUB.emp            20
PUB.dept           10
PUB.tst            34
```

basically i need to search row which start with "PUB." and if found then read till next 20 character. and append in excel file in two column..

please help .. thank you

Comment: Just do it with [sed](http://sed.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^PUB/ {print substr($0, 0, 23)}' t1.txt
```

- `/^PUB/` matches records starting with `PUB`
- For the matched records, `print substr($0, 0, 23)` prints the first 23 characters (the first 3 are `PUB`)

**Example:**

```
% cat t1.txt 
table             column size time
PUB.emp            20    1k   00.4
PUB.dept           10    3k   003
PUB.tst            34    1K   034

% awk '/^PUB/ {print substr($0, 0, 23)}' t1.txt
PUB.emp            20  
PUB.dept           10  
PUB.tst            34
```

Comment: How i can put in excel in two column ?

Comment: It doesn't even have to be this complicated; you just want the first two columns, regardless of the amount of whitespace between them. `awk '/^PUB/ {print $1, $2}'`. Importing the data into excel is going to ignore the specific spacing between columns anyway.